# How can I get post id from url?

Tags: php, url

blog.php

URL:

```
<a href="read.php/<?=seo($post_title).'/'.$post_id?>" class="abtn">Read</a>
```

I want to get post_id from url. But I don't know how?
I will be glad if you can help me.

read.php

```
<?php
   
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?";
    $select_all_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
                            
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts)) {
        $post_date = $row["post_date"];
        $date = strtotime($post_date);
        $newdate = date("d/m/Y", $date);
        $post_title = $row["post_title"];
        $post_text = $row["post_text"];
        $post_image = $row["post_image"];
   }                     
?>
```

Comment: It should be in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: Okay thanks but how? How should the codes be?

Comment: I cannot write your code for you because I do not know how you want to use the code. You can check the query string array by writing `print_r($_GET);` to see what you have in the array and go from there as required by your usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advice next solution:

```
<?php
    // get page URI and split it by '/'
    $uri_arr = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    // get post_id and prevent sql injection
    $post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $uri_arr[2]);

    // run query
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $post_id";
    $select_all_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts)) {
        $post_date = $row["post_date"];
        $date = strtotime($post_date);
        $newdate = date("d/m/Y", $date);
        $post_title = $row["post_title"];
        $post_text = $row["post_text"];
        $post_image = $row["post_image"];
    }
                
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the codes. But it didn't work. I am getting this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Son\blog-icerik.php on line 51     /    Line 51:  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts))

Comment: What error you got? Can you post what return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']? Look exapmle here: https://phpize.online/?phpses=fb6ec6b21bc3008e1bd7fda6216e56ba&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: Error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given on line 51 Line 51: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts))

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => son [2] => read.php [3] => lorem-ipsum-has-been-the-industry's-standard-dummy-text-ever-since-the-1500s [4] => 42 ) post_id: read.php

Comment: So you need get `$uri_arr[4]` it will get `42` as post_id

Comment: Okay okay i chage this: $uri_arr[2] to $uri_arr[4]. And now its working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Codes worked fine but css file not working on read.php page.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what happens with css. May be you need ask separate question about it, and provide more details.